# Как сделать дамп / восстановить дамп postgres из nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Подскажите, как сделать дамп базы postgres и восстановить его из под nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

[Точно так же, как без nodejs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/backup.html), через [child_process](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options)

```
const child_process = require('child_process');
const credentials = {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'postgres',
    pass: 'postgres',
    port: 5432,
    db_name: 'db_game2'
}

const dump_command = `pg_dump postgresql://${credentials.user}:${credentials.pass}@${credentials.host}:${credentials.port}/${credentials.db_name} > dump_${credentials.db_name}_${Date.now()}.sql`;
const dump_result = child_process.execSync(dump_command);
console.log(dump_result.toString());

const restore_command = `pg_restore postgresql://${credentials.user}:${credentials.pass}@${credentials.host}:${credentials.port}/${credentials.db_name} < dump_${credentials.db_name}_${Date.now()}.sql`;
const restore_result = child_process.execSync(dump_command);
console.log(restore_result.toString());
```